# What can we do with [restart] and [reboot]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

#### Problem:

We have these two tags:

- [restart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/restart) (x100)
- [reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reboot) (x187)

"restarting" could mean anything, e.g. services, applications, daemons, and computers. "rebooting" only affects computers (the tag wiki also mentions that).

Two ideas:

- Should we retag those from "restart" that actually mean "rebooting"?
- Should we merge them into one big "restart" tag?

---

#### These 75 "restart" questions are actually about "rebooting":

- [Can hardware get damaged from restarting a computer too often?](https://superuser.com/questions/399195)
- [Completely random computer restarts (crashes?) on any OS](https://superuser.com/questions/385591)
- [in windows 7, during startup, why do my icons go blank and then reappear](https://superuser.com/questions/381896/)
- [PC restarts while booting](https://superuser.com/questions/379509/)
- [Prevent Windows Vista from restarting/shutting down, ever](https://superuser.com/questions/379407)
- [Is there some way to prevent any and all restarts? Not just from Windows Update?](https://superuser.com/questions/375958/)
- [Will restarting the computer a lot (about 10 times in 2 minutes) damage the motherboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/375063/)
- [is it possible to toggle among different OS in a multi-boot PC without restart?](https://superuser.com/questions/368884/)
- [HP laptop doesn't boot, endlessly restarts](https://superuser.com/questions/362565/)
- [How does the computer turn itself on when told to 'restart'?](https://superuser.com/questions/357570/)
- [Computer doesn't boot, continuously restarts; possible disk error](https://superuser.com/questions/357445/)
- [What is the difference between a hard and a soft reboot?](https://superuser.com/questions/352081/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-and-a-soft-reboot)
- [Remotely shutting down the system (restarting) and instant booting](https://superuser.com/questions/349034/remotely-shutting-down-the-system-restarting-and-instant-booting)
- [Computer restarts itself when I'm playing certain games](https://superuser.com/questions/349005/computer-restarts-itself-when-im-playing-certain-games)
- [Is it possible to set Windows 7 to download updates now, but install them on the next shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/346833/is-it-possible-to-set-windows-7-to-download-updates-now-but-install-them-on-the)
- [How can I make Debian restart to GRUB?](https://superuser.com/questions/344823/how-can-i-make-debian-restart-to-grub)
- [Computer automatically shuts down after a period of idling](https://superuser.com/questions/343362/computer-automatically-shuts-down-after-a-period-of-idling)
- [Laptop restarts again and again](https://superuser.com/questions/341890/laptop-restarts-again-and-again)
- [My PC takes more than 10 minutes to enter OS choice menu](https://superuser.com/questions/341732/my-pc-takes-more-than-10-minutes-to-enter-os-choice-menu)
- [Macbook pro reboots during the first boot process](https://superuser.com/questions/337675/macbook-pro-reboots-during-the-first-boot-process)
- [What is the difference between restarting the computer once and restarting the computer twice?](https://superuser.com/questions/335280/what-is-the-difference-between-restarting-the-computer-once-and-restarting-the-c)
- [My system restarts on pressing Windows key and mutes/unmutes on pressing Ctrl key](https://superuser.com/questions/321318/my-system-restarts-on-pressing-windows-key-and-mutes-unmutes-on-pressing-ctrl-ke)
- [Workstation restarts randomly - no BSOD - temperature/power supply problem?](https://superuser.com/questions/320644/workstation-restarts-randomly-no-bsod-temperature-power-supply-problem)
- [PPTP VPN Setup Issue; forces restart](https://superuser.com/questions/320294/pptp-vpn-setup-issue-forces-restart)
- [File and print sharing disabled after each reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/319315/file-and-print-sharing-disabled-after-each-reboot)
- [Computer stuck in reboot loop after unplugging power cord](https://superuser.com/questions/317623/computer-stuck-in-reboot-loop-after-unplugging-power-cord)
- [Hibernate: Restart instead of Shutting Down](https://superuser.com/questions/314289/hibernate-restart-instead-of-shutting-down)
- [When I restart my computer then sometimes it hang at BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/309925/when-i-restart-my-computer-then-sometimes-it-hang-at-bios)
- [XP Laptop Restarting](https://superuser.com/questions/304369/xp-laptop-restarting)
- [How does a computer restart itself?](https://superuser.com/questions/294681/how-does-a-computer-restart-itself)
- [How to auto login after Windows Update restart?](https://superuser.com/questions/281939/how-to-auto-login-after-windows-update-restart)
- [windows xp error, restarts on enabling LAN connection](https://superuser.com/questions/280347/windows-xp-error-restarts-on-enabling-lan-connection)
- [Restart a windows computer without shutdown.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/270846/restart-a-windows-computer-without-shutdown-exe)
- [Desktop cannot restart (it will shut down) - Multiple OS's tried](https://superuser.com/questions/262448/desktop-cannot-restart-it-will-shut-down-multiple-oss-tried)
- [Why do some programs require a restart after install?](https://superuser.com/questions/261908/why-do-some-programs-require-a-restart-after-install)
- [Why does restarting a computer solve wifi connectivity issues?](https://superuser.com/questions/256957/why-does-restarting-a-computer-solve-wifi-connectivity-issues)
- [Ubuntu mono crash, restart](https://superuser.com/questions/251215/ubuntu-mono-crash-restart)
- [Why does my computer freeze and make a terrible buzzing noise every once in a while?](https://superuser.com/questions/245476/why-does-my-computer-freeze-and-make-a-terrible-buzzing-noise-every-once-in-a-wh)
- [How to fix regular hanging/restarts in my windows XP SP3](https://superuser.com/questions/237512/how-to-fix-regular-hanging-restarts-in-my-windows-xp-sp3)
- [How to install Snow Leopard Server over Regular Snow Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/234416/how-to-install-snow-leopard-server-over-regular-snow-leopard)
- [Restart PC via remote desktop with Explorer.exe dead](https://superuser.com/questions/230619/restart-pc-via-remote-desktop-with-explorer-exe-dead)
- [Motherboard will fully reboot, except with reset/shutdown button](https://superuser.com/questions/225424/motherboard-will-fully-reboot-except-with-reset-shutdown-button)
- [Vista reboots during loading, tried the usuals, and there is a problem finding the OS](https://superuser.com/questions/218077/vista-reboots-during-loading-tried-the-usuals-and-there-is-a-problem-finding-t)
- [Should my PC continually reboot when there is no RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/211660/should-my-pc-continually-reboot-when-there-is-no-ram)
- [Windows XP Timezone getting changed automatically on restart](https://superuser.com/questions/210007/windows-xp-timezone-getting-changed-automatically-on-restart)
- [Difference between Turning off a computer and Restarting it?](https://superuser.com/questions/206351/difference-between-turning-off-a-computer-and-restarting-it)
- [Why would my computer automatically restart after "shutdown" and "sleep"?](https://superuser.com/questions/202830/why-would-my-computer-automatically-restart-after-shutdown-and-sleep)
- [Can I restart a PC remotely if it is unreachable (down)?](https://superuser.com/questions/200055/can-i-restart-a-pc-remotely-if-it-is-unreachable-down)
- [Windows 7 won't restart properly](https://superuser.com/questions/199261/windows-7-wont-restart-properly)
- [Troubleshooting desktop PC not booting if network and USB ports are connected](https://superuser.com/questions/191439/troubleshooting-desktop-pc-not-booting-if-network-and-usb-ports-are-connected)
- [Disable Auto-Restart Prompt after Windows Update (in Windows Vista/7)](https://superuser.com/questions/189806/disable-auto-restart-prompt-after-windows-update-in-windows-vista-7)
- https://superuser.com/questions/187770/whats-wrong-with-my-pc
- [Why does my PC restart after logon or at the welcome screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/185406/why-does-my-pc-restart-after-logon-or-at-the-welcome-screen)
- [Laptop logging out of window manager a few minutes after boot up and login](https://superuser.com/questions/183521/laptop-logging-out-of-window-manager-a-few-minutes-after-boot-up-and-login)
- [vs [Shutdown + Start]](https://superuser.com/questions/179040/vs-shutdown-start)
- [WindowsXP won't start on my COMPAQ Presario - restarting help](https://superuser.com/questions/178712/windowsxp-wont-start-on-my-compaq-presario-restarting-help)
- [How to cancel a restart in Mac OS X 10.6](https://superuser.com/questions/175781/how-to-cancel-a-restart-in-mac-os-x-10-6)
- [Why do I need restart computer after installing new software?](https://superuser.com/questions/171590/why-do-i-need-restart-computer-after-installing-new-software)
- [Why would I need a reboot after installing?](https://superuser.com/questions/171248/why-would-i-need-a-reboot-after-installing)
- [Windows Wont Boot After Power Outage?](https://superuser.com/questions/158335/windows-wont-boot-after-power-outage)
- [System restarting after pressing scan on rootkit revealer](https://superuser.com/questions/157022/system-restarting-after-pressing-scan-on-rootkit-revealer)
- [My computer won't start because it keeps restarting](https://superuser.com/questions/157015/my-computer-wont-start-because-it-keeps-restarting)
- [Windows 7 restarts while being idle](https://superuser.com/questions/146892/windows-7-restarts-while-being-idle)
- [Unusual Restart](https://superuser.com/questions/108661/unusual-restart)
- [How to shut down the computer without the update on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/104771/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-without-the-update-on-windows-7)
- [Windows XP restarting repeatedly after a fresh restore](https://superuser.com/questions/100135/windows-xp-restarting-repeatedly-after-a-fresh-restore)
- [How do I restart Linux (Ubuntu) from the command-line?](https://superuser.com/questions/81005/how-do-i-restart-linux-ubuntu-from-the-command-line)
- [Ubutnu 9.10 samba after restart](https://superuser.com/questions/77969/ubutnu-9-10-samba-after-restart)
- [Disable prompts to Restart after Windows Update on XP Home](https://superuser.com/questions/77463/disable-prompts-to-restart-after-windows-update-on-xp-home)
- [Windows XP restarts itself suddenly](https://superuser.com/questions/38392/windows-xp-restarts-itself-suddenly)
- [System Restart menu with no keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/37662/system-restart-menu-with-no-keyboard)
- [Black screen after Windows startup](https://superuser.com/questions/34063/black-screen-after-windows-startup)
- [blue screen right after new xp install](https://superuser.com/questions/33715/blue-screen-right-after-new-xp-install)
- [Ubuntu networking error on startup, works with restart](https://superuser.com/questions/24131/ubuntu-networking-error-on-startup-works-with-restart)
- [Why does installing Visual Studio 2010 beta require a restart?](https://superuser.com/questions/17356/why-does-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-require-a-restart)

Comment: I don't think we should merge those, [tag:reboot] is more specific than [tag:restart] and I feel we should keep it that way. I wonder how many questions are tagged [tag:restart] instead of [tag:reboot] by accident...

Comment: Needless to say that given these statistics one big "restarting" tag would make sense. Or not?

Answer (score 6):

As you've pointed out, "*restart*" by itself can refer to a lot of different things.  As the [restart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/restart) tag doesn't refer to any particular topic, it doesn't convey much useful information.  I'd definitely say this tag should be deleted.  The [reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reboot) tag refers to a specific process--restarting a computer or operating system--and should not be deleted.

We want every tag to convey useful information, representative of the nature of the question.  A tag that doesn't refer to any specific topic is as good as nothing.